# For $0\le m\le M$, let $p$ satisfy $\left(1-\frac1M\right)^m(1-p)=\frac1e-\frac1M$. Why is it that $p=O\left(\frac{M-m}{M}\right)$?

Tags: analysis, inequality

For $M$ large enough, by taking logarithms and Taylor series, it can be checked that 
$$\left(1-\frac1M\right)^M \ge \frac1e - \frac1M$$

For $0\le m\le M$, let $p$ be a parameter satisfying 
$$\left(1-\frac1M\right)^m(1-p)= \frac1e - \frac1M$$
Someone claims 
$$p=O\left(\frac{M-m}{M}\right)$$
I am wondering why it is true?

**Further information: ** we can assume $M, m$ are nonnegative integers and $m<M$.

Comment: This does not seem to hold. For example, let $x=(M-m)/M$ ($0\leq x\leq 1$). When $x\rightarrow 0$, $p$ does not go to zero, i.e. $p/|x|$ may not be bounded.

Comment: @Pythagoras Why would that matter? You're only concerned with what happens as $x \rightarrow 1$.

Comment: @RiverLi That sounds a good condition. If one fixes $m<M$, and let $M$ grow, this would work. However if $m$ and $M$ are allowed to vary, then the estimate $p=O((M-m)/M)$ is problematic. What would it mean if $m=M$ in the first place?

Comment: @RiverLi Thanks. When I said it is a good condition, I meant it works. Maybe you can expand it as an answer.

Comment: @RiverLi I think $m<M$ works. You don't need any constant bound for the ratio. Numerical experiments seem to verify this. See my answer.

Comment: @RiverLi Only if $m$ attains $M$. Otherwise, that ratio is bounded by a constant.

Comment: @RiverLi Experimentally it seems to get to about 3.21... as $M$ grows and $m=M-1$.

Comment: @RiverLi Why are you not convinced that $\frac{p}{\frac{M-m}{M}}$ is bounded by a constant? Do you see a flaw in my answer?

Comment: @RiverLi Missed your last comment before. I was assuming $m$ to be an integer, for some reason, so I'm my answer you could take that constant $c$ to be 1.

Comment: @RiverLi You're right. I just assumed they'd be integers, so I didn't consider that case. Perhaps OP could clarify.

Comment: @Connor Are $m,M$ integers? Otherwise, the statement cannot hold, as per this conversation.

Comment: @broncoAbierto Yes, we can assume $m,M$ are nonnegative integers. We can even assume $m<M$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the inequality $1+x\le e^x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ twice and $m<M$ are integers, we have

\begin{align}
p&=1-\frac{e^{-1}-M^{-1}}{(1-1/M)^m}\\
&\le 1-\frac{e^{-1}-M^{-1}}{e^{-m/M}}=\frac{M-e^{m/M-1}M+e^{m/M}}{M}\\
&\le \frac{M-(1+m/M-1)M+e^{m/M}}{M}\\
&=\frac{M-m+e^{m/M}}{M}=O(\frac{M-m}{M}).
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

First, note that you need to assume $m<M$. Otherwise, if $m=M$ then $\frac{M-m}{M}=0$ and the condition cannot be satisfied.

Elementary manipulations yield
$$
p = 1 - \frac{1}{e(1-1/M)^m} + \frac{1}{M(1-1/M)^m}.
$$

Now, $\log(1-1/M)$ is asymptotically equivalent to the reciprocal of the derivative of $\log(M-1)$. That is,
$$
\log(1-1/M)=\log((M-1)/M)=-\log(M)+\log(M-1) = -\log(M/(M-1)) \approx {-1/(M-1)}.
$$
So $(1-1/M)^m\approx \exp\left(-\frac{m}{M-1}\right).$

Thus, it suffices to analyze the asymptotic behaviour of
$$
1 - \frac{\exp\left(\frac{m}{M-1}\right)}{e} + \frac{\exp\left(\frac{m}{M-1}\right)}{M} 
$$
$$
= \frac{Me-M\exp\left(\frac{m}{M-1}\right) + \exp\left(\frac{m}{M-1}+1\right)}{Me} 
$$
$$
= \frac{M-M\exp\left(\frac{m}{M-1}-1\right) + \exp\left(\frac{m}{M-1}\right)}{M} .
$$

Now observe that for $0\leq m \leq M-1$, it is
$$
\frac{M}{e}-1 \leq M\exp\left(\frac{m}{M-1}-1\right) - \exp\left(\frac{m}{M-1}\right) \leq M-e.
$$

Thus, $M\exp\left(\frac{m}{M-1}-1\right) - \exp\left(\frac{m}{M-1}\right)=\Theta(M)$, which implies $m=O\left(M\exp\left(\frac{m}{M-1}-1\right) - \exp\left(\frac{m}{M-1}\right)\right)$. This, in turn, implies the result.

Comment: I suppose it depends on what $p$ is a function of. $m$ should no be allowed to vary freely independently of $M$, as I believe was discussed above. For the big-O statement to make sense, I think $p$ should be a function of $M$. It would help if OP cited a source, or gave more details.

Comment: I am not sure why you need the $1/(M-1)$ approximation? I think it is more clear that $(1-1/M)\approx\exp(-1/M)$. And I am not sure if the error term matters here. (When you use $\approx$)

Comment: @Connor It's just a way to turn the expression into $\frac{M-\text{something}}{M}$, which is convenient in order to show the result.

Comment: @broncoAbierto The analysis of the main term seems correct. But will the errors in $\approx$ matters in the later calculation?

Comment: @Connor No. As $M$ grows, the error becomes smaller, so it doesn't affect the big-O relationship.